# SPARQL Property Paths in ARC2

Tags: php, syntax, properties, path, sparql

I tried to run the following query with arc2 in php but the * (ZeroOrMorePath) is not working. The query is valid, I checked it in Protege.

```
PREFIX ab: <http://www.mysite.de/testing.owl#> 
SELECT ?name WHERE {?name rdfs:subClassOf* ab:subj}
```

This query returns all Subclasses and sub-Subclasses and so on.

Is there a way to do the same in arc2?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no. According to [1] there is no support for SPARQL 1.1

[1] https://github.com/semsol/arc2/issues/57

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any suggestions how I can achive this query on my server with my own ontology?

Comment: In PHP? I'm not aware of any PHP RDF APIs besides ARC2. I know Java  based APIs like Apache Jena or RDF4J that support SPARQL 1.1, both of which also provide CLI commands for running SPARQL on a given file.